# Leaflet in R mangling terra RGB rasters

Tags: r, leaflet, terra, rgb

I'm working with an RGB raster in leaflet (some Landsat data). I'm stretching and sampling it down so that it's small enough.  The following works great.

```
# stretch and then resample like geom_spatraster
landsat_rgb_stretched <- stretch(landsat_colors_1230[[1:3]],
                                 minq = 0.02, maxq = 0.98) |>
  spatSample(size = 5e5, as.raster = TRUE, method = "regular")

# set RGB channels
RGB(landsat_rgb_stretched) <- 3:1

# plot
plotRGB(landsat_rgb_stretched)
```

[image]

But, when I try and put it into leaflet, I get a muddled mess. It's close, but, very weird. I'm trying to figure out why.

```
# interactive plot
leaflet() |>
  addRasterImage(landsat_rgb_stretched)
```

[image]

Do I need to do something else to specify how levels are weighted, or are there arguments I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of terra::plotRGB for leaflet is leafem::addRasterRGB. See https://r-spatial.github.io/leafem/reference/addRasterRGB.html

Example:

```
library(leaflet)
library(leafem)

leaflet() |> 
  addRasterRGB(plainview::poppendorf, 4,3,2)
```

[image]